# While Giving from date and to date all the files in-between the dates should list in django

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

Giving from date and to date, after submitting it should list the files in-between the dates.

views.py

```
def select_date(request):
    client = Client.objects.all()
    process = Client_Process.objects.all()
    pdf = Client_files.objects.all()

    return render(request,'select_date.html', {'pdf':pdf,'client':client,'process':process})
```

models.py

```
class Client_files(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    client_process = models.ForeignKey(Client_Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    File_Name = models.FileField()
    Pages = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Status = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    class Meta:
        db_table : 'client_files'
```

UI Image

[image: i this image i just displayed all the files but i need only selected date files]

In this image I just displayed all the files but I need only the selected date files.